# Check if song is buffering in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, buffer

I have the following piece of code:

```
var song:Sound;
var sndChannel:SoundChannel;
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(2000);

function songLoad():void {
    song.load(new URLRequest(songs[selected]),context);
    sndChannel = song.play();
}
```

Now I want to be able to check if the song is buffering or not. Is there a way to do this? Or should I approach it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you could use the [isBuffering](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html#isBuffering) property of the Sound object.

Maybe you could check it periodically with a Timer or an Event.EnterFrame listener, as long as the sound has not been completely downloaded (i.e. until Event.COMPLETE fires). After that point, it makes no sense to check `isBuffering`, for obvious reasons, so you could remove the Timer or EnterFrame.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that property. 
Thanks a lot!